# Convert date string to date object so it can be used with moment

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have a date string like this: `"Mon Jul 18 2016 21:35:14 GMT+00:00"` and would like to use this in moment to format it to `"MM-DD-YYYY"`, it does that but throws a warning pointing back to this issue https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407

Is there a way that I can convert the above to a date object and then use it in moment for formatting something like:

```
moment(Mon Jul 18 2016 21:35:14 GMT+00:00).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
```

Comment: Right, did you read through that issue? It tells you what to do; namely, provide a format string inside the `moment(string, format)` call...

Comment: When parsing, you should always give the parser the format, otherwise you're just hoping it guesses correctly. E.g. `moment('Mon Jul 18 2016 21:35:14 GMT+00:00', 'ddd MMM DD yyyy hh:mm:ss Z').format('MM-DD-YYYY')`. BTW, that is a very ambiguous format.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the string and the format within the moment call:

```
var date_as_string = "Mon Jul 18 2016 21:35:14 GMT+00:00";
var current_format = "ddd MMM DD yyyy HH:mm:ss Z";

moment(date_as_string, current_format).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
```

You are telling the function what format your string is in so that it can parse it correctly.